# XOXCO tagging, how to add in KO binding to dynamic a tag

Tags: javascript, plugins, knockout.js

I'm using XOXCO's tagging plugin. 
Currently it always displays the remove x however I only want this to be displayed if the page is in edit mode. Currently I am using a knockout data bind for the editmode:

```
data-bind="visible: $root.editMode()==true"
```

This is the XOXCO code for displaying the tag and x for removing.

```
 if (d != "" && h != true) {
            a("<span>").addClass("tag").append(a("<span>").text(d).append("  "), a('<a>',{
                id: "campaign-tag",
                href: "#",
                title: "Removing tag",
                text: "x"
            }).click(function() {
                return a("#" + f).removeTag(escape(d))
            })).insertBefore("#" + f + "_addTag");
            g.push(d);
            a("#" + f + "_tag").val("");
            if (e.focus) {
                a("#" + f + "_tag").focus()
            } else {
                a("#" + f + "_tag").blur()
            }
            a.fn.tagsInput.updateTagsField(this, g);
            if (e.callback && c[f] && c[f]["onAddTag"]) {
                var i = c[f]["onAddTag"];
                i.call(this, d)
            }
            if (c[f] && c[f]["onChange"]) {
                var j = g.length;
                var i = c[f]["onChange"];
                i.call(this, a(this), g[j - 1])
            }
        }
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: I don't understand where exactly your problem lies. But you might simply add an 'editing-mode-enabled' css class to a container, and use CSS to only show the links when that class is present.

Comment: Well I'm using this:
http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

The problem is the remove icon is always showing but I only want it if data bind is in editMode(). I'll get the css trick a try but editMode isn't a class...

Comment: What do you mean, editMode ist not a class? Just add `data-bind="css: { editmode: $root.editMode }"` to the parent container of your tags, and use that to hide the links with CSS if they are not needed. Something like `a[title="Removing tag"] { display: none; }` and `.editmode a[title="Removing tag"] { display: inline; }`